# How to set default style `lang` in of all Vue components in project?

Tags: vue.js

I don't want to write `lang="stylus"` in every component. How can I make this the default?

Comment: isn't this more of a code editor problem?

Comment: I don't think so. The build system looks at that attribute to determine how to process the content (using Sass/Stylus/Less/etc).

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is, when I create a `<style>` using VSCode, for me, it automatically creates `<style lang="scss">` when I type `style` and hit auto fill. I think for WebStorm (when I tried it) When you create a new `vue` file it would automatically create the `template`, `script` and `style`.

Comment: I see, that's more of a workaround than the actual solution. Not everyone on a team will have the same editor and configuration.

Comment: There's rule in the module in `webpack.base.conf.js` which has `{
        test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass'
      },` maybe if you make it `style!stylus` only, it would process it as stylus (also change relevant stuff). I haven't tested it, but it's probably your best bet to my knowledge

Comment: That won't work with `.vue` files, which are handled with `vue-loader`. Maybe `vue-loader` needs an option.